Looking for a movie title about a journalist who framed a murder!
I'm trying to remember a movie title. Can't remember actors or director. It dates back to 2000-2010, and it's about a journalist who is imprisoned for murder. It's a US movie and it takes place in the US.
During the film, he tries to prove his innocence, based on a film he made that states that he framed himself into that murder scene in order to prove police incompetence. In the end, it turns out he actually murdered that woman because she would reveal that his other reports were fake. The woman is recognized because of a tattoo she has on the her fingers.

The movie is Beyond a Reasonable Doubt (2009), without a doubt.
C.J. Nicholas is a young reporter who made a name for himself with a faked story. He tries to expose a D.A who is faking evidence by framing himself for a murder which he actually did commit to cover up his previous story, thus killing 2 birds with one stone. 
His exculpatory evidence is destroyed by a crooked cop, but he still manages to escape conviction.
He is caught out by his ADA girlfriend who recognizes a tattoo on the dead woman from Nicholas's video of his original award-winning story.

